# jQuery - Youtube Pop Video

Tags: jquery, css, youtube, colorbox

I am using Color Box to have a onclick Pop Video player. I have set up the plugin and set the link of the youtube video.

OnClick the Modal pop up opens but the video does not seem to play.

[image]

[Link](http://104.236.218.36/)

Comment: Check console...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your youtube url to embed `http://www.youtube.com/embed/nPtdE5iH63Q` you cannot force youtube `/watch...` page to be embeded in your page, it is not allowed.